# How to perform a subtract across only one column of a matrix?

Tags: r, math

I have a large character matrix:

```
Chromosome   Start    End   ... 
1            1        5000  ...
2            1        4000  ...
...          ...      ...
```

I would like to subtract 1 from each entry of the second column. The first idea that comes to mind is to separate each column, convert the second as numeric, perform the subtraction and use cbind to patch everything together. However, since I have over 20 columns, I want something more efficient.

I would appreciate your input.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... Do you want `Data$Start <- Data$Start - 1`? If you're looking for something more efficient, you could try a loop.

Comment: @SimonG, he has a character matrix. He can't perform what you wrote because, well it is a character matrix. He also can't convert only one row to numeric class, because, well, it is a character *matrix*

Comment: Now I wonder why there even is a character matrix full of numbers to substract. A data.frame could be more suitable in this case. At least for the question that is actually asked (I am aware that matrices have merits).

Comment: Because a data frame is a very inefficient data structure, it is alwways preferable to work with matrices and lists if you have huge data set

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your replies. Well, I need a character matrix because I used strsplit to create these entries. However, now I would like to perform a simple operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `gsubfn` package as it is designed especially for cases like that, in particular:

```
library(gsubfn)
dat[, 2] <- gsubfn("\\d", function(x) as.numeric(x) - 1, dat[, 2])
dat
##      Chromosome Start End   
## [1,] "1"        "0"   "5000"
## [2,] "2"        "0"   "4000"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just (now assuming character matrix but would also work w/ datafreme.)

```
dat[ ,2 ] <- as.numeric(dat[, 2 ])-1
```

Comment: It's a matrix, right?  I think you may want `dat[,2] <- as.numeric(dat[,2])-1`. Your answer is specific to data frames.